# Not able to get user responses in SharePoint 2013 survey list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list

I am not able to get the user responded answers from the survey list. I am aware that survey questions and choices are stored in list field collections and answers are in list item collection.

Please see below code

```
    var listItemEnumerator = allListItems.getEnumerator();
    var listFieldEnumerator = surveyFields.getEnumerator();

    // To collect response internal IDs from list field collection
    var intCount = 0;
    while (listFieldEnumerator.moveNext()) 
    {
        this.currentField=listFieldEnumerator.get_current();

        if(currentField.get_fieldTypeKind()==SP.FieldType.choice || currentField.get_fieldTypeKind()==SP.FieldType.multiChoice)
        {
            responseArray[intCount]=currentField.get_internalName();
            intCount=intCount+1;
        }
    }

    //Now get user survey response from list item collections by passing the collected internal IDs
    intCount = 0;
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext())
     {
         var oList = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
         Answers[intCount] = oList.get_item(responseArray[intCount]);
         intCount=intCount+1;   
     }
```

`currentField.get_internalname()` will give me ID of field like `_x0031__x002e__x0020_Is_x0020_th`

If we pass to `listitem.get_item("_x0031__x002e__x0020_Is_x0020_th")` will give me responded answer like

1. Yes.

is there any method that gives me item value from field collection?

Here objective is to get questions and user selected answer to send it to another list. I am able to get questions but not able to get answer.